# Creating a collection and some objects from a class

Tags: excel, vba, testing, wizard, algorithmic-trading

I have this Excel VBA code, and I just dont understand how the control flow works. It uses some kind of clever trick. Can someone help me fill in the details?

Basically, the code creates a collection, it creates some objects from a class "cls_FX", and fills the collection with the objects. Then there is a test which I dont understand. It looks like this. And nowhere has the string "Test" been added to the collection, as far as I can see. Can someone explain the code? What is the strategy of the strange test Err.Number=0? Why test with 0?

cls_FX:

```
Option Explicit
Public str_fx                       As String
Public col_Years                    As New Collection
Public str_Test                     As String
```

Code:

```
var_FX_Array = Array("USD", "GDP", "EUR")
For j = 0 To 3
    Dim ci_cls_FX As New cls_FX
        ci_cls_FX.str_fx = var_FX_Array(j)
        col_FX.Add ci_cls_FX, ci_cls_FX.str_fx
        Set ci_cls_FX = Nothing
Next j


str_fx = "USD"
Err.Clear
col_FX(str_fx).str_Test = "Test"
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    str_Year = .Offset(i, 2)
    ....
```

Comment: `col_FX(str_fx).str_Test = "Test"`?

Comment: Side note, but that snake case just looks so wrong.

Comment: Doesn't the above throw an index out of range exception?

Comment: ^ I'm guessing OP shortened `var_FX_Array` for purposes of this question.

Comment: J also goes from 0 to 5 but the referenced array only has three items.

Comment: A dictionary would be better suited in this scenario because you can check if the FX key exists without playing with the error codes.

Comment: *Trick* maybe yes. *Clever*? No way.

Comment: Guessing there's an `On Error Resume Next` statement somewhere above this snippet. This isn't clever code at all, it's poorly written, uses impossible-to-read identifier names (why do they read like SQL Server collations?? drop the Hungarian prefixing and lose these underscores). Remove the `On Error Resume Next` statement, it'll reveal how buggy that "clever" code actually is ;-)

Comment: Ok guys, maybe this was not clever at all. Yes I shorted the array to 3 items, it was 5 items. And there is a On Error Resume Next statement above, true. Wow, you really catched these quick! I am just trying to learn VBA and have great difficulties, it is difficult! I wonder, can someone explain how this test works? Why does it test for "Test"? That word has not been added. What is the reasoning behind this, what is the big picture? Why do you check if Err.Number=0? What does it do? I dont understand the big picture. Any hints where to start digging? Please explain the code? :)